# How can I collect data on the same date and create a new table

Tags: python, arrays, date, datetime, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  d

df = pd.read_csv("coronavirus2_dataset.csv",sep=",") df.head(20)
df.head(20)
```

[image]

Here I want to collect the data on the same date and make a new table. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Sum up the "Confirmed", "Deaths", and "Recovered" columns for each date?

Comment: I need to separate the date data. Since there is a lot of data from the same date, I have to collect the dead and dried numbers of the data on the same date and allocate them day by day.

Comment: to separate by day we can create a new dataframe like this: `df[df.Date == 'date u want']`

Comment: Please clarify your question. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data with a specific date with:

```py
df[df.Date == "01/22/2020 12:00:00"]
```

To add this as a row to a new dataset:

```py
df_new = pd.DataFrame()  # Create a new, empty, dataframe
df_new.append(df[df.Date == "01/22/2020 12:00:00"])  # Append the data with the specific date
```